# Perlin Noise acting strange

Tags: vb.net, perlin-noise

I am trying to implement a 2D Perlin Noise in VB.Net. I've spent the whole day searching for sources that explain the subject and one of the most notable was this article by [Hugo Elias](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm)

Most of the implementation went well. On the exception of a very important part that did not seem to work in VB.Net, causing overflows.

```
function Noise1(integer x, integer y)
    n = x + y * 57
    n = (n<<13) ^ n;
    return ( 1.0 - ( (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);    
end function
```

In VB.net I translated it to

```
Private Function Noise(tX As Integer, tY As Integer) As Double
    'Return a double between -1 & 1 according to a fixed random seed
    Dim n As Integer = tX + tY * 57
    n = (n << 13) Xor n
    Return (1.0 - ((n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + BaseSeed) And &H7FFFFFFF) / 1073741824.0)
End Function
```

Which cause overflows.

Since the idea seem to be to simply generate a fractional number between -1 and 1. I've made this little function which create a Integer Number based on the coordinates and BaseSeed. BaseSeed(999999) being the base for every noise I'll create in this particular part of my game.

```
Private Function Noise(tX As Integer, tY As Integer) As Double

    Dim tSeed As Integer
    tSeed = WrapInteger(789221, BaseSeed, (tX * 1087) + (tY * 2749))
    RandomGenerator = New Random(tSeed)
    Return (RandomGenerator.Next(-10000, 10001) / 10000)

End Function
```

WrapInteger simply makes sure that the number will always be in the range of an integer, to avoid overflow errors.

```
Public Function WrapInteger(ByVal Lenght As Integer, ByVal Position As Integer, ByVal Movement As Integer) As Integer
    Lenght += 1
    Return ((Position + Movement) + (Lenght * ((Abs(Movement) \ Lenght) + 1))) Mod Lenght
End Function
```

When I fire it up with a Persistence of 0.25, 6 Octaves and a starting frequency of 2. this is what I get. This is a 128x128 pixel bitmap that I scaled.

[Result](http://s27.postimg.org/gpw7yb81v/Noise.jpg)

Anyone have an idea of why it would be so linear? When I look at this picture I have the feeling that it's not far from the truth, as if it only worked in 1D. All suposition.

Below you will find my entire PerlinNoise Class. I think the rest of it is just fine, but I added it for reference purpose. Beside, I haven't been able to find a single VB implementation of Perlin Noise on the internet. So I guess if I can fix this one, it might help others. There seem to be alot of question about Perlin noise malfunction on StackOverflow

```
Public Class cdPerlinNoise
Private RandomGenerator As Random
Private BaseSeed As Integer
Private Persistence As Double
Private Frequency As Integer
Private Octaves As Integer

Public Sub New(tSeed As Integer, tPersistence As Double, tOctaves As Integer, tFrequency As Integer)
    Frequency = tFrequency
    BaseSeed = tSeed
    Persistence = tPersistence
    Octaves = tOctaves
End Sub

Private Function Noise(tX As Integer, tY As Integer) As Double
    Dim tSeed As Integer
    tSeed = WrapInteger(789221, BaseSeed, (tX * 1087) + (tY * 2749))
    RandomGenerator = New Random(tSeed)
    Return (RandomGenerator.Next(-10000, 10001) / 10000)
End Function

Private Function SmoothNoise(tX As Integer, tY As Integer) As Double
    Dim Corners As Double = (Noise(tX - 1, tY - 1) + Noise(tX + 1, tY - 1) + Noise(tX - 1, tY + 1) + Noise(tX + 1, tY + 1)) / 16
    Dim Sides As Double = (Noise(tX - 1, tY) + Noise(tX + 1, tY) + Noise(tX, tY - 1) + Noise(tX, tY + 1)) / 8
    Return (Noise(tX, tY) / 4) + Corners + Sides
End Function

Private Function InterpolateCosine(tA As Double, tB As Double, tX As Double) As Double
    Dim f As Double = (1 - Cos(tX * 3.1415927)) * 0.5
    Return tA * (1 - f) + tB * f
End Function

Private Function Interpolate2D(tX As Double, tY As Double) As Double
    Dim WholeX As Integer = CInt(Fix(tX))
    Dim RemainsX As Double = tX - WholeX
    Dim WholeY As Integer = CInt(Fix(tY))
    Dim RemainsY As Double = tY - WholeY

    Dim v1 As Double = SmoothNoise(WholeX, WholeY)
    Dim v2 As Double = SmoothNoise(WholeX + 1, WholeY)
    Dim v3 As Double = SmoothNoise(WholeX, WholeY + 1)
    Dim v4 As Double = SmoothNoise(WholeX + 1, WholeY + 1)

    Dim i1 As Double = InterpolateCosine(v1, v2, RemainsX)
    Dim i2 As Double = InterpolateCosine(v3, v4, RemainsX)

    Return InterpolateCosine(i1, i2, RemainsY)

End Function

Public Function PerlinValue(tX As Double, tY As Double) As Double
    Dim Total As Double = 0
    Dim Frequency As Double
    Dim Amplitude As Double
    For i = 0 To Octaves - 1
        Frequency = Frequency ^ i
        Amplitude = Persistence ^ i
        Total = Total + (Interpolate2D(tX * Frequency, tY * Frequency) * Amplitude)
    Next
    Return Total
End Function

Public Function ScaleNoise(ByVal tX As Double, ByVal tY As Double, ByVal OutputLow As Double, ByVal OutputHigh As Double) As Double
    Dim Range1 As Double
    Dim Range2 As Double
    Dim Result As Double
    Range1 = 1 - -1
    Range2 = OutputHigh - OutputLow
    '(B*C - A*D)/R1 + n1*(R2/R1)
    Result = (((1 * OutputLow) - (-1 * OutputHigh)) / Range1) + ((PerlinValue(tX, tY) * (Range2 / Range1)))
    If Result < OutputLow Then
        Return OutputLow
    ElseIf Result > OutputHigh Then
        Return OutputHigh
    Else
        Return Result
    End If
End Function

End Class
```